# validation rule on two pick fields based on values

Tags: validation-rule

I have two pick list fields product__c and Assigned_group__c

I am trying to write a validation if value on product__c picklist is DR user can only select L2 value on Assigned_group__c picklist and shows error if try to select other values on Action_Owner__c.

I have written this rule:

AND(
ISPICKVAL(Case__r.Product_Type__c, "Digital Risk"), ISPICKVAL( Action_Owner__c, "L2" ))

but its not firing.

Comment: Well, your rule as written doesn't match your description. Is it `Assigned_group__c` or `Action_Owner__c`?

Comment: its Action_Owner__c edited in description as well

Answer (score 0):

I added NOT condition and it worked.

AND( 
ISPICKVAL(Case__r.Product_Type__c, "Digital Risk"), NOT(ISPICKVAL( Action_Owner__c, "L2" )))